# primefaces set values to selectCheckboxMenu

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Trying to set values in selectCheckboxMenu using primefaces 4.0

/ my xhtml code /

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{A.b}" label="C"  valueChangeListener="#{myValidator.validate}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{d.availableItems}"/>
    <p:ajax update="some_id"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

/ myValidator /

```
public void validate(ValueChangeEvent event){
    Object[] oldValues = ((Object[]) event.getOldValue());
    SelectCheckboxMenu input = (SelectCheckboxMenu)event.getComponent();
    input.setSelectedValues(oldValues);
}
```

by I get a strange error

```
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert [Ljava.lang.Object;@40bb23 of type class [Ljava.lang.Object; to interface java.util.List
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:867)
```

Comment: the error is asking, are sure that `d.availableItems` is a list ?

Comment: The problem comes from the `d.availableItems" ... availableItems` has to be a List<String>, not a String[]. What are you trying to accomplish with the `validate()` method?

Comment: @HatemAlimam d.availableItems is a map.values(), where each item is a SelectItem

Comment: @rion18 it has to check some checkboxes depends of the condition. Can i do it somehow without changing d.availableItems?

Comment: @user1448906 is b a List<String> or a String[]?

Comment: @rion18 it's a List<String>

Comment: @user1448906 It should be a `String[]`. The selected values in a selectedCheckboxMenu should be an `Array`... And by the way, `d.available` items can be a `Map`.

Comment: @rion18 i've found a kind of workaround by myself, but I appreciate ur attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem been solved by adding a validation method into the bean setter.